# slight jerkiness when scrolling down through a 5 div home page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 5 divs which represent a home page.  Each div takes up a full 100% of vh.  As I scroll down through each div, the first 3 are smooth, but once I hit the 4th div as I scroll down it becomes slightly jerky.  I have tried turning off JS in the browser.  I have lowered the background images to really low resolution such as 400kb and this does not solve it.  Is there anything else that could cause scrolling to become jerky.  This is mainly noticeable when using a MacBook track pad as 2 finger scrolling is pretty smooth.  It wouldn't be noticeable on a Windows mouse I don't think.  The only elements on the div are a background image that takes up the full background, and a button in the centre.

```
    <div id="photography" class="image-portfolio-section">   
            <div class="image-portfolio-button-container">
                <a style="text-decoration:none;" class="motion-gallary-button-white" href="country.php">IMAGE PORTFOLIO</a>
            </div>
    </div>

css styling:

.image-portfolio-section { 
background-image: url('../assets/DSC_3214-min.JPG');
height: 100vh;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
margin-bottom: .3rem;
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr); 
}

.image-portfolio-button-container{

grid-row: 3 / 4;
display: grid;
width: 280px;
height: 4rem;
justify-self: center;
text-decoration: none;
align-self: center;
}

.image-portfolio-button-container a:hover {
background-color: #967549;
color: #fff;
}
```

I also have some javascript on the page but this relates to other divs and not this div which has jerky scroll.

```
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
    <script src="js/purecookie.js"></script>

   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>


    $(window).ready(function() {
        let centerLogoOne = Array.from(document.querySelector('.home-center-logo-one').children);
        centerLogoOne.forEach((item) => { 
        item.style.animation = 'fadeIn ease ' + Math.random()*10 + 's';
        });

        let wildLifeWordOne = Array.from(document.querySelector('.videoWordOne').children);
        wildLifeWordOne.forEach((item) => {
            item.style.animation = 'fadeIn ease ' + Math.random()*10 + 's';
        });

        let wildLifeWordTwo = Array.from(document.querySelector('.videoWordTwo').children);
        wildLifeWordTwo.forEach((item) => {
            item.style.animation = 'fadeIn ease ' + Math.random()*10 + 's';
        });

        let wildLifeWordThree =          Array.from(document.querySelector('.videoWordThree').children);
        wildLifeWordThree.forEach((item) => {
            item.style.animation = 'fadeIn ease ' + Math.random()*10 + 's';
        });


        const mq = window.matchMedia( "(max-width:768px)" );

        if (mq.matches) 
        {
            let video = document.querySelector('video');
            video.setAttribute('autoplay','true');
            video.setAttribute('muted','true');
            video.setAttribute('loop','true');
            video.setAttribute('playsInline','true');
            video.setAttribute("src", "assets/Mobile_Background.mp4");
        }

    });



</script>
```

Comment: Scroll jank can be caused by a lot of different elements. It could be js, css or even html. I suggest you begin by creating a copy of the page (including a copy of the css, js, html and images). Then remove html code one by one untill the scrolling jank dissapears. Do the same steps for your javascript and css code. When have have an isolated testpage that only contains the code that causes the scroll jank. Then we can search together after you've posted a StackOverflow snippet: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: I you want to debug it yourself via the inspector you can follow this debugging tutorial: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/web-perf It will go deeper into scroll jank and how to debug it.

Comment: @Wezelkrozum I created a new branch and started with CSS , deleted line by line, and no change, then moved to HTML deleted line by line and no change.  I removed all Javascript from the file and also disabled it in the browser and nothing has worked.  The debugging link looks quite complex, but looks like that may be the only route at this stage.